# Converting jar to exe file in Eclipse plugin

Tags: software-recommendation, eclipse

I am developing an Eclipse plugin. When I extract my Eclipse plugin project to my system, using *Export> Plugin Development > Adding Fragments&Plugins*. After exporting it, it's not executing when I double-click on the `.jar` file. How can I change it into `.exe` format?

Comment: Are you using Ubuntu? .exe is a strange filetype for Java code on a Unix-like system.

Comment: @EliahKagan no am using Windows 7., if there is any other chances for converting it.?

Answer (score 3):

In Ubuntu `exe` files won't do much good for you, this is not Windows :). You should just launch your `jar` file with in `java -jar mypackage.jar` in a shell script or make the `jar` file executable by `chmod +x filename` or by right clicking on it in Nautilus and setting the executable flag on the Permissions page.

For Java applications, the nice way of doing things is putting an `sh` file for Unices and a `bat` file for Windows next to the `jar`, and launching the application from these files.

Comment: Thanks for your words,But i need to create an .EXE format file,then only the client can access my project,and evenmore i try to open the .JAR file but it not responding.,

Comment: Of course it is not responding, if it is not executable.

Comment: Can you suggest any ideas to convert JAR to .EXE file format.?already tried out the software JSMOOTH,etc.,

Comment: I don't exactly understand what you want to achieve. If you develop a plugin, why do you want an exe?

Comment: I am creating an Eclipse plugin project that produce an another perspective window as OUTPUT. Here which .exe file should be given to the Clients for their access,Because we won't give the entire coding into them.

Comment: You can export a jar without sources, no need for an exe for that

Answer (score 0):

If you want to execute .jar files you might try jarwrapper.

Source: https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/precise/jarwrapper/

Comment: Thanks.,But i convert it through the JSMOOTH Software.,

Comment: @KarthickG If you've resolved your problem to your satisfaction it is customary to answer your own question so that others can benefit from your experience. Please do so. Thank you!

Comment: Yeah sure..Am get it through Jsmooth Software,whether it is correct or not,i don't know,But it Helps me.,